# Issue with memcpy

Tags: c, memcpy

I am developing in Cocoa / Xcode and have an `int *` array containing values.
When I want to use `memcpy` to shift values in the array, it transfers only 0s.

e.g.

- Array contains values as 1 2 3 4
- `memcpy(array,array+2*sizeof(int),2*sizeof(int));`

result: 0,0,3,4

Is there a better alternative to memcpy, or something I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the right way to do what you want is:

```
memcpy(array, array + 2, 2*sizeof(int));
```

That's because in the 2nd argument of memcpy pointer arithmetic is being done, and anything that's being added to "array" pointer is considered as being a multiple of an integer's size. So in this case saying "array + 2" means "the integer pointer `array' plus two times the size of an integer".

Comment: Personally I would prefer "memcpy(array, array+2, 2*sizeof array[0] );". Will work independent from the type of array, even in a macro.

Answer (score 0):

The manpage to memcpy says, that the regions should not overlap. Try memmove instead.

Comment: Thanks, but the regions do not overlap here because I am just copying the 3 and 4 to the 1 and 2. Tried with memmove however and result is unfortunately the same...

Comment: Why in the world would you use `memcpy` for 2 `int`s rather than just writing `array[0]=array[2]; array[1]=array[3];`??